# Saving data with a built name in R

Tags: r

In an R script, I assign a name to some data. The name depends on parameters. I do this using

```
number<-1
assign(paste("variable", as.character(number), sep=""),2)
```

The above accomplices the same as `variable1<-2`. Now I want to save the result for later

```
save(?,file=paste("variable",as.character(number),".RData",sep=""))
```

What code can go in the ? slot where it should say `variable1` except I need to construct this name using paste or some similar technique. Simply putting `get(paste("variable",as.character(number),".RData",sep=""))` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`save` can also use `list` as parameter.  According to `?save`

> list - A character vector containing the names of objects to be saved.

Thus, we specify the object name as a string (`paste0('variable', number)`) for the `list` argument and `file` as the one used by OP (or make it more concise with `paste0` (`as.character` is not necessary as integer/numeric gets automatically convert to type `character` in `paste`

```
save(list = paste0('variable', number),    
    file = paste0("variable", number, ".RData"))
```

Check for the file created in the working directory

```
list.files(getwd(), pattern = '\\.RData$')
#[1] "variable1.RData"
```